# alias_method on ActiveRecord::Base results in NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a model inheriting directly from `ActiveResource::Base`, and I'm trying to run `alias_method` for most of the columns in the record's table, but the result is a NameError:

> NameError: undefined method `address_line_1' for class`
>   LeadImport::Base'

Yet I can access the attribute:

```
LeadImport::Base.new.address_line_1 #=> nil (not error)
```

My class has a table column named `address_line_1`, so I fail to see the problem.

```
class LeadImport::Base < ActiveRecord::Base
    alias_method :address_1, :address_line_1
end
```

*specs: Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.8*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According a site I found, you're supposed to use alias_attribute instead:

> The problem is that ActiveRecord doesn't create the accessor methods
>   on the fly until the database connection is live and it has parsed the
>   table schema. That's a long time after the class has been loaded.

```
class LeadImport::Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :address_1, :address_line_1
end
```